# Bash: Convert string into array?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have been Googling to no avail, so I would appreciate someone's kind help a lot.

I have a string of filenames that will be generated, and each filename is separated by the character `|`.

For instance, the string of filenames looks similar to:

`/home/user/something or other.txt|/home/user/Downloads/something else.txt|/home/somewhere/there are spaces definitely.txt|/home/user/there are always spaces.txt|/home/user/Documents/spaces are always present.txt`

I would like to split this string into an array, using the character `|` to split up the filenames and their locations.

I have tried this:

`IFS='|' read -ra array <<< "$string"`

but it does NOT work and gives me the following error message:

`Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Perhaps someone much more clever than me has the solution? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: How exactly are you running this? are you sure it's being interpreted by bash (not sh for example)?

Comment: I have #!/bin/bash at the top of the .sh file, if that answers your question. Then I run sh filename.sh to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct - *for bash*

> I have #!/bin/bash at the top of the .sh file

Good

> Then I run sh filename.sh to run it.

Here's the problem - you're explicitly telling the system to ignore the shebang, and run the script with `sh`. That likely resolves to `/bin/sh` which on Ubuntu is the POSIX `dash` shell by default.

Instead, just make your script executable

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

and then run it using

```
./filename.sh
```

which will ensure the correct interpreter is used. See also

- [What is the difference between sh and ./ when invoking a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364145/what-is-the-difference-between-sh-and-when-invoking-a-shell-script)

Comment: Thank you! This has appeared to fix the problem. It also seems to work if I run bash filename.sh

Comment: @etsnyman yes `bash filename.sh` will work - but try to get out of the habit of second-guessing the correct interpreter (that's what the shebang is for)

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reading string into an index array with a user defined delimiter using mapfile:

```
$ string='1|2|3|4'; \
  mapfile -td \| <<< $string; echo ${MAPFILE[@]}
```